# error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Persistence' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine.XR.WSA' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm currently developing an app for android. In my code, I use the namespace `UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Persistence`. When I'm launching the app on the editor, i have no errors, but when I try to build this to send it to my phone, I get the following one :

> The type or namespace name "Persistence" does not exist in the
>   namespace "UnityEngine.XR.WSA". Are you missing an assembly
>   reference?"

Isn't it strange since it's working on the editor? How do i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`WSA`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.WSA.html) stands for **`Windows Store Apps`**. This is only available when building apps for `Universal Windows Platform`. Especially `UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Persistence` afaik is or at least was previously developed by [Microsoft](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/mixed-reality/blob/master/mixed-reality-docs/persistence-in-unity.md) and is even only used in particular for the [HoloLens](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsholographic-persistence.html).

It throws no exceptions in the Editor but afaik some [`#if` preprocessors](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) make sure that it also does nothing there.

---

It is not available when building an App for `Android` platforms.

To remove the error in your script you can use [`#if` preprocessors](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) and [Platform dependent compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) like

```
#if UNITY_WSA
    // anything using the UnityEngine.XR.WSA namespace
#else
    // alternative implementation for different platform
#endif
```

however, the functionality ofcourse will not be available on Android so if you need something similar you have to use another library or come up with one ;)